# How can I upgrade to a newer version of btrfs-tools?

Tags: 12.04, btrfs

The btrfs tools package in 12.04 appears outdated and doesn't take advantage of the newer features such as scrub introduced in kernel v 3.0. How can I upgrade to a newer version? Do I need to compile from source?

I've installed the debian package from wheezy, same version is in sid. The package has the most up to date features, which I need. No system instability so far. Hope ubuntu gets it in the repository soon. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

There are some instructions for getting the latest version at [btrfs wiki](http://btrfs.ipv5.de/index.php?title=Btrfs_source_repositories). There is also a bug report asking for a newer version in ubuntu [bug #894456](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools/+bug/894456)

Answer (score 0):

Compile from source might be a good idea; you could also check if there is any package on the debian tree. (Look for the sid tree).
In any case, trying to change a package like a fs managing package might corrupt the operating system or worse corrupt the file-system itself.

Answer (score 0):

This quantal package installed on precise for me and seems to be working well:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/btrfs-tools/0.19+20120328-4

It may or may not work for you.