# Cannot use 'btrfs balance' to convert to raid1

Tags: 12.04, btrfs

I'm trying to convert a 2 drive btrfs array on Ubuntu 12.04 to use RAID1. Following the [instructions on the btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion) I've tried this command, with no success:

```
valorin@gimli:~$ sudo btrfs filesystem balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /
ERROR: 'filesystem balance' requires 1 arg(s)
```

I've checked for documentation, but I can't seem to find any documentation for this command.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For future reference, converting is now (in current versions) done using the balance subcommand (without "filesystem"), so it would be: `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the extra arguments with the balance command, you need to install a newer version of btrfs-tools than is available for Ubuntu 12.04.

It's [pretty easy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118842/how-can-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-btrfs-tools) (see first answer) to compile a new version of btrfs-tools from the btrfs git repo. There are also binary packages from Debian sid or Ubuntu 12.10 that might work.